# jQuery set Height in Iframe for Internet Explorer Height becomes bigger and bigger

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, height

I try to set dynamically the height of an iframe after it loads. And then id bind the iframe, so after a mousemoveEvent the new height is set.

```
$(myIframe).load(function(){

    var iframeHeight = $(myIframe).height();
    $(myIframe).height(iframeHeight);

    $(myIframe).contents().find(IframeID).bind('mousemove', function(){
        iframeHeight = $(myIframe).height();

        $(myIframe).height(iframeHeight);

    });


});
```

So my Problem ist that in FireFox, Chrome, Opera and so on it works fine. The internetExplorer 7/8/9 sums the new height to the old height. So on every mousemove the height becomes bigger and bigger.

What can I do to tell the InternetExplorer to do like the other browsers.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this issue when i have tried to set iframe height to it's content with extra 200px space, and each time i changed to content the iframe became bigger in 200px in IE only, and as far as i can remember now i didn't use jquery at the end and instend i used this:

```
var iFrame = document.getElementsById('myFrame');
iFrame.style.height = (parseInt(iFrames[i].contentWindow.document.body.offsetHeight) + 200) + 'px';
```

well this was my soulation for my issue and i'm hoping it will be helpful for you..

Comment: Hello, today i could solve the problem. I calculated the height based on the HTML Tag of the frame. Instead I used BODY for the Height calcutation.

Comment: `var iframeHeight = $(myIframe).contents().find('body').height();`